# ordeing grouped item with laravel querybuilder

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have a table with following data

```
id    name     category_id
1      A           1
2      B           1
3      C           2
4      D           2
```

I have done the following query

```
DB::table('tablename')
                  ->select('id')
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                  ->groupBy('category_id')                                
                  ->get();
```

It returns id 3 and 1,but I need id 4 and 2...

Please help me to find the solution

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Following code.hope that it will work for you.

```
DB::select( DB::raw('SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY tablename.id DESC ) t group by t.category_id order by t.id desc));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `Laravel`, but the following SQL query may help you.

```
select max(id) from table_name 
group by category_id
order by id desc
```

convert the same into `Laravel` syntax and use.

Answer (score 0):

You need `selectRaw` for this:

```
DB::table('tablename')
      ->selectRaw('max(id)')
      ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
      ->groupBy('category_id')                                
      ->get();
```